# Error reversing queue in recursive Java method

Tags: java, recursion, queue, reverse

I am trying to write a **recursive** method to reverse all elements in a queue.

In an abstract class **myQueue** which implements **Queue< T >** interface is my **reverse** method:

```
public void reverse() {
  T temp = dequeue();
  Queue<T> bufferQueue = new Queue<T>();

  if(!(temp == null)){
    bufferQueue.enqueue(temp);
  }

  if(!(isEmpty())) {
    reverse();
  }else{
    while(!(bufferQueue.isEmpty())){
       Queue.enqueue(bufferQueue.dequeue);
    }
  }

}
```

The interface **Queue< T >** has the following methods which are *complete*(and implicitly do as defined):

```
public boolean isEmpty();
public int size();
public void enqueue(T e);
public T dequeue();
public T front();
```

#### My goal:

In my **reverse method**, I am aiming to constantly **dequeue** (remove first element) from my Original Queue recursively till my queue is empty. Every time I dequeue I will place that object in a **temporary** Queue. When my queue is empty, than I do **enqueue** from my **temp queue** back in to my original Queue.

My first problem is defining a new temporary queue, in my case **bufferQueue**. I get the following:

```
1. ERROR at solution.java (at line 12)
Queue<T> bufferQueue = new Queue<T>();
                           ^^^^^
Cannot instantiate the type Queue<T>
```

Comment: Queue is an interface you need to instantiate a concrete implementation of Queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Queue` is an interface. You can't create an instance of an interface.
Check the JavaDoc for Queue and choose a Class that implements `Queue` instead:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

What you are trying to accomplish is surprisingly simple and doesn't require recursion at all, just the available methods on a concrete class, like `ArrayDeque` + your custom reverse method. Also, you don't need the intermediate `bufferQueue`. This should work nicely:

```
public class MyQueue<T> extends ArrayDeque<T>{
    public void reverse() {
      T[] contents = toArray(T[]);
      clear();

      if(contents != null){
        for(int i = contents.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
            add(contents[i]);
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right. Am I heading in the right direction as to which my recursion is defined?

Comment: I think you are better off extending a concrete Queue class so you can simply add the reverse() method, instead of having to implement the multiple abstract methods in the Queue interface

Comment: Also, call the `poll()` method instead of `dequeue()`. Not sure where the `dequeue()` method comes from. Is that a custom method?

Answer (score -2):

You need to have a concrete type there not T, T is not possible when isntantiating.

Comment: Yes it is. T the generic type in this case. In the line before the ``T temp = dequeue();`` is working.